# Play Video from SMB/CIFS file server

Tags: flutter, dart, smb

I'm a novice in SMB.

Current, I need to read and play .mp4 video files from an SMB server in flutter app.
But currently, we haven't found any possible library for this task.

Does anyone know how to open and read files in SMB from flutter app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this: [libsdms](https://pub.dev/packages/libdsm#-example-tab-)?

To play mp4 files though you need to also embed an http server in your app, since you need an http path (instead of the smb file path you get). So you need to convert your file to bits, then stream via http and play the http file in your app.

Check this for more : [http server](https://dart.dev/tutorials/server/httpserver)

Comment: Thanks so much, that's help me alot